# How can I analytically calculate the rate of thermal decomposition of calcium carbonate?

Tags: equilibrium, kinetics, decomposition

I am a first-time poster on Chemistry StackExchange, and not much of a chemist.

I'm trying to determine the rate of thermal decomposition (in mol/s) of calcium carbonate ($\ce{CaCO3}$) at various temperatures (assuming atmospheric pressure).

The best resource I could find was an old handbook about the thermal decomposition of carbonates, which gave the equilibrium constant K for this reaction at various temperatures:

[image]

From this data set, it appears that the reaction only proceeds at temperatures above 1100 K. Below this temperature, all values of K are less than 1. A value of K = 1.84 is given at 1200 K, but no further information is provided.

I essentially have three questions:

1. Is it possible to use K to calculate a reaction rate? Specifically, for this example, would it be possible to calculate what the rate of reaction is, in mol/s, at 1200 K, using the given K value of 1.84?
2. If #1 is possible, is it also possible to extrapolate the rate of reaction to higher temperatures using the low-temperature equilibrium constants? I'm mainly interested in temperatures in the range from 1200 - 1800 K.
3. If neither of the above are possible, do I simply need to find (or produce) experimental data on the rate of reaction?

Thank you!

Comment: No, the reaction rate is not related to K whatsoever.

Comment: First, the reaction rate is not related to the equilibrium constant. Second, you do not mention the unit of K. Third, the decomposition of  CaCO3 happens in a flame at about 800°C, where K is rather low, because there is practically no equilibrium in the flame. CO2 is eliminated as soon as produced.

Comment: Since a gas is involved I would be surprised if you *couldn't* obtain some sort of estimate on the forward/backward rates of reaction from this data, but it would involve many assumptions and require information about the surface properties and reactivity.